# Running Django Python on IIS 6

Tags: django, iis-6

I'm having trouble running Django on IIS 6 and was hoping someone could help!

I've followed this guide exactly a number of times: http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoOnWindowsWithIISAndSQLServer

However, when I try and view my site I always get the same message:

> The specified module could not be found.

What are the steps to fix?

Edit-----

OK - I figured this out.

I was using the wrong version of PyISAPIe. I was using version 2.5 and I had needed version 2.6 to match the version of Python I was using. Hopefully this might help anyone else who is having a similar issue!

Thanks guys for your comments below!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to install Fast CGI on IIS 6:

[Install Fast CGI on IIS6](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/248/configure-the-fastcgi-extension-for-iis-60/)

I installed PHP on IIS through the new Microsoft web application and it goes like a charme.

I suppose it will work well also for python.